# Sorting points(in 2d,3d and so on) in java

Tags: java, sorting

What is the best way to sort the points(first based on x co-ordinate and if x is same then on y co-ordinate and if y is same then based on z co-ordinate and so on.) in java without implementing sorting algorithm?

In c++ it can be done very easily(as follows) with the help of pairs.

For 2D:

```
Vector < pair < int,int > > plane;
sort(plane.begin(),plane.end())
```

For 3D:

```
Vector < pair < int,pair < int,int > > > space;
sort(space.begin(),space.end());
```

Thanks in Advance.
Shantanu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to implement a sorting algorithm.  You just need to implement a comparator, which can then be used with [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%2C%20java.util.Comparator%29).

See [*Object Ordering*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) from the Java Tutorial for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There are few options in Java.

1. `Collections.sort(List l)`

   Use `java.lang.Comparable   // For sorting only on the basis of one property`
2. `Collections.sort(List l, Comparator c)`

   Use `java.util.Comparator  // For sorting in more than one way`
3. If Uniqueness is needed, along with Sorting use `TreeSet()`

   ```
   TreeSet()   // Sorting in Natural order

   TreeSet(Comparator c)   // Sorting in more than one way.
   ```